# What is the actual return type of the filter method on a range? How do I make it a Vector?

Tags: scala

I'm completely new to Scala so bear with me please! I am going through some Scala exercises and one of them is to create a list of odd numbers from 1 to 20. This is pretty straight forward but I'm a bit confused about the return type of the `filter` method on a range.

I have the following block:

```
val lst2 = (1 to 20).filter(_ % 2 != 0)
println(lst2)
```

The output of this is:

> Vector(1, 3, 5, 7, 9, 11, 13, 15, 17, 19)

However when I explicitly set the type of `lst2` to `Vector[Int]` like the following:

```
val lst2: Vector[Int] = (1 to 20).filter(_ % 2 != 0)
println(lst2)
```

I get the this:

> 16: error: type mismatch;
>
> found   : scala.collection.immutable.IndexedSeq[Int]
>
> required: Vector[Int]
>     val lst2: Vector[Int] = (1 to 20).filter(_ % 2 != 0)
>                                             ^
>   one error found

So what's gonig on here? Is the `println` method just not giving me the correct type? How do I get the filter method to return a Vector?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The only guarantee that is provided by `filter` of `Range` is that it returns a `collection.immutable.IndexedSeq[A]`, so this compiles:

```
val lst2: collection.immutable.IndexedSeq[Int] = (1 to 20).filter(_ % 2 == 1)
```

At runtime, `lst2` just *happens to be* a `Vector[Int]`, but this is not guaranteed by the interface, so the authors of the `filter` method effectively reserve the right to change the concrete implementation to another `IndexedSeq` whenever they like. The type `Vector` is an implementation detail you shouldn't rely on.

The reason why it's printed as `Vector(...)` is that it depends on the implementation of `toString` of a concrete instance that is present at runtime, not on the statically know type (dynamic dispatch).

If you really want something with type `Vector`, just append `.toVector`:

```
val lst2: Vector[Int] = (0 to 20).filter(_ % 2 == 1).toVector
```